# Why Auth.forgotPasswordSubmit() is not sending correct response

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am trying to forgot password of cognito user pool using aws-amplify in react-typescript

```
 await Auth.forgotPasswordSubmit(
    data.username as string,
    data.code as string,
    data.password as string
  );
```

this is the method password change successfully but showing error.

Error : InvalidLambdaResponseException: Invalid lambda function output : Invalid JSON
at http://127.0.0.1:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/aws-amplify.js?v=05cc6dda:50694:19

Comment: Do you have any cognito lambda triggers set up for the user pool? In that case please check their error logs in CloudWatch to see if you find an error message there

Comment: I'd check too to see if your data is coming through. `console.log("data: ", data)`